# Piercing ear for the second time

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, cartilage, earlobes, body-piercings

Are there any risks to re-piercing the ear on the same spot as a healed previous piercing?  What about on cartilage?

Comment: Edited to fit site guidelines by removing all personalized content.  It was otherwise at risk of being closed. You may revert it if you disagree.